# onItemClick in ListView randomly changes the background color

Tags: android, listview, background-color

I am using multiple choice ListView items. The user can select multiple items. So I wanted to highlight the items selected by the user by changing either the text color or background color of the list row. I have gone through stack overflows links but didn't get the proper solution. When I am trying to do it, it is randomly changing any unselected item background color. Help!!!

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80B7DBE8"));
    SaveSelections();
}
```

Comment: are you using ArrayAdapter if so v.setBackgroundColor() wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far better than the above suggestions is to use a selector, also known as a state-list drawable.  That way, the OS takes care of all of the business of color highlighting, etc.

more explicitly, take the following xml and save it under res/drawable as something like li_background.xml (I'm using images, but feel free to swap out colors as is appropriate to your situation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_activated="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" />
    <item android:state_activated="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

and set the background of **All** ListItems in the ListView to R.drawable.li_background.  if your listView is properly configured for multiple selections (`android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"`  or `listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);` if you prefer) then android will take care of the rest.  This stuff isn't well documented, I had a hard time finding the solution and I see similar questions all the time, but the relevant dos are [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3achoiceMode)

Answer (score 4):

That randomly changing background color is due to the reason that ListView *recycles* views in its list to avoid unnecessary memory consumptions. You need to provide your own custom adapter in which you need to override **getView** method and perform some checks to highlight only those list items who have some kind of flag set to true for background color

Answer (score 2):

You probably should override getView() in the adapter, and change the row background color in there.

An example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView != null) {
        if (mSelectedPositions.contains(position)) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3fa9f5"));
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
    }
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Wagas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966550/waqas) is correct. In your adapter's `getView`, you are passed a View (called `convertView` by Eclipse's autocomplete). This is because `ListView`s recycle the views for each row. If you set a property for a given `View`, it will retain that property when it is recycled.

For this reason, you should never set the properties of anything in a given row's `View` outside the `getView` method of the Adapter backing the `ListView`.

There are a number of ways you could handle this, but the basic idea is that you want to set some piece of data that uses the `position` passed in to `onItemClick` to set a flag. Then check the flag in the Adapter's `getView` to decide how to set the background for the row's `View`.

For example, if only one item can be selected, you might just set a member variable, say `mPosition` on the Adapter itself to the position passed in to `onItemClick`, and then check in `getView` if position == mSelectedPosition to decide how to set the View. If multiple items can be selected, perhaps you set a member variable on each object contained in the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

in  onItemClick() just use adapter.notifyDataChange(); also set a flag to true;

in the getView() of your CustomAdapter use boolean flag to know whether the row was selected or not.
Then just check that flag and proceed as you want
i.e.,
if(flag){
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80B7DBE8"));
}else{
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
}